# G++ problems with std::function

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<int,int> p;

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

I am using MinGW g++ 4.8.1 which fails with

```
C:\main.cpp|4|error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)|

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\functional|1866|error: provided for 'template<class _Signature> class std::function'|

C:\main.cpp|4|error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token|
```

is this a G++ bug or am I using std::function incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::function<int(int)>` for function takes int and return int. e.g.

```
int foo(int);
```

`std::function<void(int,int)>` for function takes two ints and no return value. e.g.

```
void foo(int, int);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` takes one template argument - the type of the callable object that it wraps around. So, if you want to construct an `std::function` which returns type `Ret` and takes arguments of types `Arg1, Arg2,..., ArgN`, you would write `std::function<Ret(Arg1, Arg2,..., ArgN)>`.

(Note that the ellipses weren't meant to indicate parameter pack expansion - they are just being used in the regular mathematical sense.)

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler says, std::function takes one template argument.

Use the syntax returntype(argtype, ...)

```
int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
std::function<int(int,int)> p = foo;

int bar(int a) { return ++a; }
std::function<int(int)> q = bar;

void boo() { return; }
std::function<void()> r = boo;
```